# How to get max value from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list

I have python list of dictionaries as below. I would like to find max value of `'high'` field.

```
ohlc = [
  {
    'open' : 100,
    'high' : 105,
    'low' : 95,
    'close' : 103
  },
  {
    'open' : 102,
    'high' : 108,
    'low' : 101,
    'close' : 105
  }
  {
    'open' : 101,
    'high' : 106,
    'low' : 100,
    'close' : 105
  }
]
```

In this case function should return `high` = 108.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide a simple and easily understandable way using `for loop`, as follows:

```py
import sys
ohlc = [
    {
        'open': 100,
        'high': 105,
        'low': 95,
        'close': 103
    },
    {
        'open': 102,
        'high': 108,
        'low': 101,
        'close': 105
    },
    {
        'open': 101,
        'high': 106,
        'low': 100,
        'close': 105
    }
]

max_high = ohlc[0]['high'] to assign first high value.

for i in ohlc[1:]:
    if i['high'] > max_high:
        max_high = i['high']

print(max_high)
#108
```

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution happy to help you. I updated my answer to give you more info. :)

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the comment, I fixed my answer as you indicated :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the key parameter to the max function like so:

```py
ohlc = [
  {
    'open' : 100,
    'high' : 105,
    'low' : 95,
    'close' : 103
  },
]
print(max(ohlc, key=(lambda item: item['high'])))
```

Comment: FWIW, this could also be written as max(ohlc, key=operator.itemgetter('high'))) which might be faster than using a user-defined `lambda` function if the list has a very large number of dictionaries.

Comment: Fair enough, TIL about operator.itemgetter